# Docker container volume does not get mounted in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

The following is my actions file.

```
name: ZAP
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: owasp/zap2docker-stable
      options: --user root
      volumes:
        - /__w/actions-test-repo/actions-test-repo:/zap/wrk/
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: view file
        run: pwd
      - name: run zap
        if: always()
        run: zap-baseline.py -t https://www.example.com -g gen.conf -r testreport.html
      - name: view file
        if: always()
        run: pwd
```

I want to bind the directory /zap/wrk/ to a local directory. But when the container starts it does not mount this volume. I got the present working directory and mounted it to the docker container. Is this the correct way to do it?

[image]

Results link: https://github.com/sshniro/actions-test-repo/commit/08c0257d92b772a1d33c0b68cb8af99afdef9130/checks?check_suite_id=324032091

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Similar issues have been identified in this forum as well.
https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Container-volumes-key-not-mounting-volume/td-p/34798

The workaround is to use the options parameter.

```
name: ZAP
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: owasp/zap2docker-stable
      options: -v /__w/actions-test-repo/actions-test-repo:/zap/wrk/:rw
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: run zap
        if: always()
        run: zap-baseline.py -t https://www.example.com -g gen.conf -w testreport.md
```